# Background-Install an apk file without submit interface. What the way to do ? android

Tags: android, background, android-install-apk

Background-Install an apk file without submit interface. What the way to do it?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "background-install an apk file without submit interface"?

Comment: sorry  , i mean to install using java code   and when i use intent to install it have submit interface before install begin but i do not want show submit interface (Silent Install)

I want use it in my app.

thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Plain simple - you can't. The closest you can get is Android Market auto-updating your apps. Non-Market apps will allways require the user to accept the permissions used by the app.